# Inconsistent accessibility: Layered architecture MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i have three classes, all of them public just one of them is partial. But i have Inconsistent accessibility error.

```
public partial class University
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

        public string Province { get; set; } = null!;

        public int NumberOfStudents { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

```
 public interface IUniversityDAL : IEntityRepository<University>
    {
    }
```

```
 public class EFUniversityDAL : EFEntityRepositoryBase<University, CoreDbContext>, IUniversityDAL
    {
    }
```

Third one gives error to me.

I tried to remove public access but it didn't work

Comment: I guess `EFEntityRepositoryBase` or `CoreDbContext` is not public.

Comment: MVC is already multi-layer but none of the code posted here shows inconsistent accessibility. The only problem is antipattern of trying to put a low-level CRUD interface over a high-level Unit-of-Work/ORM. I suspect the non-EF classes have inconsistent accessibility, eg `public` on a method returning a protected or private type

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Thank you very much, I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: @Cassawena the very fact you use a CRUD class is a serious bug. Instead of abstracting or adding layers you do the exact opposite, spilling the CRUD implementation details into your controller. EF is an ORM, built to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables that need CRUD operations. A DbContext instance *is* a UoW, that detects any changes to the objects it tracks, and persists them almost transparently. By adding those CRUD classes you punch through the UoW/ORM abstraction layer almost down to the ADO.NET layer.

Comment: And, if you call `SaveChanges` on every CUD operation, you'll break the concurrency model, introducing the need for an explicit long-lived database transaction.

Comment: I am working on Data Access Layer, but I am going to look at your advices, thank you so much @Panagiotis Kanavos